# Link split and adding coma

Tags: javascript

I have some links that i need to split and remove extra text.

```
$('#extract').click(function() {
    var links = $('#links').val();
    var linksArray = links.split('https://www.example.com/add/');

    $('#ids').html('https://www.example.com/tool/Moderation?ids=');

    linksArray.forEach(function(link) {
       $('#ids').append(link.split('/')[0] + ',');
    });

});
```

All works fine. If i run link

https://www.example.com/add/31842988/topbest-something

https://www.example.com/add/31843072/topbest-something

https://www.example.com/add/29307791/topbest-something

script will split and i will have correct output with ID's 
https://www.example.com/tool/Moderation?ids=,31842988,31843072,29307791,

The issue is the comma (,) before the first and after the last number.

Comment: im confused as to what the issue is. those links all point to the same 'example domain' site. what is the error? What is the expected output? Why have you included 4 links to the same site with no explanation?

Answer (score 0):

use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and  [`Array#join(,)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

1. In `Array#map` get only first splitted value to create array
2. Then join the array using `,` its only added middle of the string
3. Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the empty arguments in array

**Code**

```
 var query = linksArray.map(link => link.split('/')[0]).filter(l=> l.trim()).join(',');
 $('#ids').append(query);
```